# Expo start results in npm install

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I've built an app, also published it already. Now I want to make a small change to the app, but after starting Expo I get an error:

"Error: React Native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project."

Starting Expo (expo start) worked in the past. But starting Expo keeps failing with this error, even after running 'npm install'.
I've also tried 'expo build:android', but that also doesn't work.

All these commands are failing, also with other Expo built apps. Also an app I worked on yesterday.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[edit]
I am using Expo 2.6.8. (which was a just available update)

Comment: Just do what the error said. run `npm install`

Comment: @Siraj done that, but it doesn't solve anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Try updating nodejs

> https://nodejs.org/en/download/

worked for me